# How to remove sharp edges when using subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: python, modifiers, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm having trouble with a subdivision surface modifier.

I'm making all with a python script

I want to get rid of sharp edges on the sides of the different levels

[image]

this is the modifier and it's applied on a plane with subdivion number of cuts at 1000

[image]

EDIT 1:
Subdivision and subsurface modifier

```
#subdivide and add surface subdivision modifier
bpy.data.objects.get("Canvas").select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts = 1000)
#bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts = 2)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
subsurf_mod = obj.modifiers.new("subsurf","SUBSURF")
subsurf_mod.levels = 3
subsurf_mod.render_levels = 6
subsurf_mod.subdivision_type = "CATMULL_CLARK"
```

Comment: i tried different changes found while searching on google, but nothing worked

Comment: Do you have edges marked as sharp? Are all the vertices welded together, that is no two vertices share the same location? Please share your mesh view. Can you share a minimum script that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: Hi, I just had to subdivide more.. anyway now the problem is with the render levels that while rendering looks like it's gettingthe viewport level value and I don't know why.. @RonJensen

Comment: I personally think the problem is not with the subdiv, but with the Python-generated topology.Maybe share that script, to explore the possibilities in there?

Comment: added the subdivion and subsurface modifier code